# Which version of eventmachine is able to work in windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, eventmachine

I'm having issues with using eventmachine 0.12.10 in my windows machine.

Now my question is, currently, which version of eventmachine is able to work?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927907/ruby-problem-installing-eventmachine-under-windows-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Windows 7

```
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]
eventmachine (1.0.0.beta.4.1 x86-mingw32)
```