# EventMachine gem workaround causes missing dll file ruby error, Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows-7, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, eventmachine

Upon cloning my first Rails 3.1.1 app, my first bundle install choked on the eventmachine 0.12.10 gem.  (I'm running Windows 7 32 bit)

I'm also using gem 'thin' as well.

I found this post that had the same problem.

[Which version of eventmachine is able to work in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659821/which-version-of-eventmachine-is-able-to-work-in-windows)

Which I integrated with this line in my gemfile:

```
gem "eventmachine", ">= 1.0.0.beta"
```

That allowed the bundle install to run but when I start the rails server I get a Ruby popup with the header ruby.exe - System Error and the text

```
The program can't start because libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll is missing from your computer.  Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

After I click OK I get this message in the console

```
Unable to load the EventMachine C extension; To use the pure-ruby reactor, require 'em/pure_ruby'
```

followed by a long stack trace (request to see if you think this will help).

I see that EventMachine gem requires a C++ compiler.  I reinstalled MinGW on my 32 bit Windows 7 machine and I added MinGW\bin to my PATH variable.

But when I look into that bin folder, the file libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll isn't there and the same error message persists.  I found this thread about the lack of that folder from 2009 but I'm not really sure what to do about it.

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=539033

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Welcome to the windows/linux compatibility hell ! Those open-source tools are not designed for Windows. In my experience, when you'll have solved this problem, you'll only run into another one, until you give up. I've gone through that. I would suggest a side-solution : running a virtualized linux on your windows machine. It's what I use and it works very well, you have apt-get and everything works immediately.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by adding

```
require "em/pure_ruby"
```

in the config/application.rb

Hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your gem file

```
gem 'eventmachine', '1.0.0.beta.4.1'
```

Also note that if you switch back to a unix based OS, you will have to use `1.0.0.beta.4`.

Comment: In other words just do `gem 'eventmachine', ">= 1.0.0.beta.4", "<= 1.0.0.beta.4.1"` for cross-platform goodness!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because eventmachine is dynamically linked to the mingw dlls.

You can:

```
require 'devkit'
```

on the top of your script. This will temporarily enhance your path with the path to the mingw devkit.

[Source](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit)