# I Can't install EventMachine in Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, eventmachine

I just try to install EventMachine with RubyGems : (gem install eventmachine).
I use Windows 7 x64.

I get this error :

```
C:/Ruby/193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... no
checking for rb_thread_check_ints()... yes
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for windows.h... yes
checking for winsock.h... yes
checking for main() in -lkernel32... yes
checking for main() in -lrpcrt4... yes
checking for main() in -lgdi32... yes
checking for main() in -lssl... no
creating Makefile

make
generating rubyeventmachine-i386-mingw32.def
compiling binder.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from project.h:137:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
binder.h:35:34: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:138:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
em.h:91:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:92:76: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:93:56: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:95:57: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:96:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:97:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:98:55: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:99:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:101:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:106:42: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:123:45: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:132:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:45:61: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:46:112: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:47:69: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:49:73: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:62:75: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:63:74: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:64:77: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:65:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:99:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:100:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:102:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:105:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
compiling cmain.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from project.h:137:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
binder.h:35:34: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:138:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
em.h:91:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:92:76: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:93:56: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:95:57: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:96:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:97:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:98:55: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:99:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:101:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:106:42: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:123:45: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:132:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:45:61: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:46:112: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:47:69: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:49:73: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:62:75: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:63:74: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:64:77: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:65:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:99:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:100:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:102:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:105:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:98:71: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:109:122: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:119:79: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:129:83: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:260:85: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:270:84: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:280:88: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:290:51: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:300:70: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:320:55: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:546:70: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:669:68: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp: In function 'int evma_send_file_data_to_connection(long unsigned int, const char*)':
cmain.cpp:752:6: error: cannot convert 'stat*' to '_stati64*' for argument '2' to 'int _fstati64(int, _stati64*)'
make: *** [cmain.o] Error 1
```

I use Ruby 1.9.3
Do you have an idea ?

Ruby has some problems in Windows,
I hesitate to use Cygwin, what do you think ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby: problem installing EventMachine under Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927907/ruby-problem-installing-eventmachine-under-windows-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Rubygems to get EM:

```
gem install eventmachine --pre
```

Installed it plenty of times myself, never had an issue. The `--pre` is what will get it to install correctly on Windows.

Also, the first Google result for [`install eventmachine on windows`](https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=install+eventmachine+on+windows&oq=install+&aq=0p&aqi=p-p2g8&aql=&gs_l=hp.3.0.35i39l2j0l8.1283.2145.1.3127.8.8.0.0.0.0.170.1003.2j6.8.0...0.0.bDtXLAzLkAQ&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=f2111a854f511ad4&biw=1366&bih=645) leads to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6927907/366051), which is the exact same as yours.

EDIT:
This answer was prior to EM 1.0's release. Now, standard `gem install eventmachine` should work and install 1.0.3.

Comment: there is a known problem with EM and ruby 1.9.3-p194 on windows see: https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/319 better to stick to 1.9.3-p125

Comment: @ALoR Thank you. I haven't worked with EM lately so I was unaware of this issue.