# Bundler / eventmachine install issue (Rails / Windows)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, eventmachine

I am having trouble installing Bundler in Windows. I first do a gem install, which seems fine (although only one gem is installed?):

```
C:\furious-ocean-6331>gem install bundler --pre
Successfully installed bundler-1.2.0.pre.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.2.0.pre.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.2.0.pre.1...</code>
```

Then, I bundle install, and I get this beaut:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Using rake (0.9.2.2)
Using i18n (0.6.0)
Using multi_json (1.3.5)
Using activesupport (3.2.2)
Using builder (3.0.0)
Using activemodel (3.2.2)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using journey (1.0.3)
Using rack (1.4.1)
Using rack-cache (1.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.1)
Using hike (1.2.1)
Using tilt (1.3.3)
Using sprockets (2.1.3)
Using actionpack (3.2.2)
Using mime-types (1.18)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.10)
Using mail (2.4.4)
Using actionmailer (3.2.2)
Using arel (3.0.2)
Using tzinfo (0.3.33)
Using activerecord (3.2.2)
Using activeresource (3.2.2)
Using addressable (2.2.8)
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
Using bundler (1.2.0.pre.1)
Using coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
Using execjs (1.3.2)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2)
Using json (1.7.3)
Using rdoc (3.12)
Using thor (0.14.6)
Using railties (3.2.2)
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
Using daemons (1.1.8)
Installing eventmachine (0.12.10) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
.

        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... no
checking for rb_thread_check_ints()... yes
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for windows.h... yes
checking for winsock.h... yes
checking for main() in -lkernel32... yes
checking for main() in -lrpcrt4... yes
checking for main() in -lgdi32... yes
checking for main() in -lssl... no
creating Makefile

make
generating rubyeventmachine-i386-mingw32.def
compiling binder.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is val
id for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is v
alid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from project.h:137:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
binder.h:35:34: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:138:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
em.h:91:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:92:76: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:93:56: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:95:57: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:96:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:97:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:98:55: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:99:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:101:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:106:42: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:123:45: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:132:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:45:61: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:46:112: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:47:69: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:49:73: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:62:75: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:63:74: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:64:77: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:65:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:99:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:100:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:102:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:105:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
compiling cmain.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is val
id for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is v
alid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from project.h:137:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
binder.h:35:34: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:138:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
em.h:91:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:92:76: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:93:56: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:95:57: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:96:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:97:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:98:55: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:99:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:101:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:106:42: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:123:45: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:132:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:45:61: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:46:112: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:47:69: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:49:73: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:62:75: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:63:74: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:64:77: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:65:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:99:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:100:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:102:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:105:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:98:71: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:109:122: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:119:79: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:129:83: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:260:85: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:270:84: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:280:88: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:290:51: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:300:70: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:320:55: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:546:70: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:669:68: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp: In function 'int evma_send_file_data_to_connection(long unsigned int,
 const char*)':
cmain.cpp:752:6: error: cannot convert 'stat*' to '_stati64*' for argument '2' t
o 'int _fstati64(int, _stati64*)'
make: *** [cmain.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9
.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmach
ine-0.12.10/ext/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing eventmachine (0.12.10), and Bundler cannot co
ntinue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '0.12.10'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I tried `gem install eventmachine -v '0.12.10'`, but when I do `bundle install` again, I get the same huge error about my eventmachine.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

EDIT: I tried installing `gem install eventmachine --pre` as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927907/ruby-problem-installing-eventmachine-under-windows-7) post, but I got the same result.

Comment: what are you trying to build here? Do you have to use rails here? EventMachine can be used even without rails

Comment: OS is 64-bit Vista (oops...). I have to use Rails - I need to clone a Rails app from git.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421728/i-cant-install-eventmachine-in-windows?rq=1)  might help or try adding `gem "eventmachine", "~> 1.0.3"` on any line in your gem file it is in the main directory of your app

Comment: @TusharGupta I am not thats why I said might I am having a similar problem and manny people get it fixed that way however there is a problem with evenmachine itself if that is the error then the only way I can point you is this https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/pull/411 but that more advanced