# Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler

Tags: ruby, heroku, rubygems

Having issues trying to push for the first time to a heroku app, Ive created the app online and added the heroku git. but after doing

```
git push heroku master
```

And I get the following response

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Sinatra app detected
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7
       Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
       Using --without development:test
       You have modified your Gemfile in development but did not check
       the resulting snapshot (Gemfile.lock) into version control

       You have added to the Gemfile:
       * reloader

       You have deleted from the Gemfile:
       * fleakr
       FAILED: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler

To git@heroku.com:boxing-api.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:boxing-api.git'
```

What is it that I am missing?

I am running on Windows

------ EDIT -----

This is what I get from running "bundle install"

```
C:\Users\Steve\Documents\GitRespository\score card app>bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Using multi_json (1.0.4)
Using activesupport (3.1.3)
Using builder (3.0.0)
Using i18n (0.6.0)
Using activemodel (3.1.3)
Using addressable (2.2.6)
Using backports (2.3.0)
Using bson (1.5.2)
Using bson_ext (1.5.2)
Using daemons (1.1.8)
Using dm-core (1.2.0)
Using dm-migrations (1.2.0)
Using dm-timestamps (1.2.0)
Using dm-validations (1.2.0)
Using escape_utils (0.2.4)
Installing eventmachine (0.12.10) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
.

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... no
checking for rb_thread_check_ints()... yes
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for windows.h... yes
checking for winsock.h... yes
checking for main() in -lkernel32... yes
checking for main() in -lrpcrt4... yes
checking for main() in -lgdi32... yes
checking for main() in -lssl... no
creating Makefile

make
generating rubyeventmachine-i386-mingw32.def
compiling binder.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is val
id for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is v
alid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from project.h:137:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
binder.h:35:34: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:138:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
em.h:91:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:92:76: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:93:56: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:95:57: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:96:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:97:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:98:55: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:99:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:101:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:106:42: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:123:45: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:132:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:45:61: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:46:112: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:47:69: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:49:73: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:62:75: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:63:74: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:64:77: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:65:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:99:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:100:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:102:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:105:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
compiling cmain.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is val
id for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is v
alid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from project.h:137:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
binder.h:35:34: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:138:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
em.h:91:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:92:76: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:93:56: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:95:57: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:96:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:97:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:98:55: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:99:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:101:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:106:42: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:123:45: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:132:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:45:61: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:46:112: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:47:69: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:49:73: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:62:75: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:63:74: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:64:77: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:65:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:99:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:100:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:102:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:105:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:98:71: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:109:122: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:119:79: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:129:83: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:260:85: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:270:84: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:280:88: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:290:51: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:300:70: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:320:55: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:546:70: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:669:68: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp: In function 'int evma_send_file_data_to_connection(long unsigned int,
 const char*)':
cmain.cpp:752:6: error: cannot convert 'stat*' to '_stati64*' for argument '2' t
o 'int _fstati64(int, _stati64*)'
make: *** [cmain.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmach
ine-0.12.10 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/ext/g
em_make.out
An error occured while installing eventmachine (0.12.10), and Bundler cannot con
tinue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '0.12.10'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 4):

Run `bundle install`, add *Gemfile.lock* to your repository, commit, and then push again.
Heroku needs both *Gemfile* and *Gemfile.lock* to install your dependencies.

---

Check this out for your Event Machine build problem: [Ruby: problem installing EventMachine under Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927907/ruby-problem-installing-eventmachine-under-windows-7)

Comment: I have it as far as I know (still new to ruby/heroku etc) my app is hosted here https://github.com/elmo61/score-card-app As you can see I have a gemfile.lock and gemfile. do they need to sync up together? whats the best way to do this?

Comment: type `git status` to ensure that your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock have both been added.

Comment: @Steve I forgot to mention the most important part: running `bundle install`.

Comment: I successfully deployed your app in Heroku (http://pure-snow-1401.heroku.com/) -- It doesn't work though, but that's an application error and has nothing to do with your actual problem.

Comment: interesting how did you go about it.... i added the error i got from running bundle install... :(