# Rails / Windows: Cloning a application that requires eventmachine 0.12.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, eventmachine

I am cloning an application (developed on a Mac) that requires `eventmachine <0.12.10>`. Unfortunately, [this particular version of eventmachine is incompatible with Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927907/ruby-problem-installing-eventmachine-under-windows-7), so I am getting thrown half a billion errors.

What should I do?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** `eventmachine <0.12.10>` is required directly. It is also required indirectly by `thin` (although `thin` simply requires an `eventmachine` with version >=0.12.06).

Comment: you should specify what it means "requires". it requires directly or indirectly via a specific gem. you can get this information checking the Gemfile.lock

Comment: Sorry - added clarification to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and found out that you need the --pre version of eventmachine in order to run thin. You can install eventmachine and thin manually or you can add this to your gem file:

gem "eventmachine", ">= 1.0.0.beta"  # same as eventmachine --pre
gem 'thin'

This is working for me without a glitch so far.

Comment: Ah ha. Did you add that stuff to the gem file and then run bundle install, or did you run all the needed gems manually?

Comment: Actually both. I first played with the gems manually until I got it working. Google is your friend... Then I deployed to a test machine and wasn't happy with not having the gems in the Gemfile so I didn't install the gems manually and researched how to install the --pre gem in the Gemfile. Tried it and it worked. Google is a good friend... After that I went back to my local machine, added the gems to Gemfile, didn't uninstall the gems that I had manually installed, tried the app and... it's still working! I can't complain about how things went this time. I'm glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

ok, right. Well. Do you absolutely, need Thin? Cannot you work, initially with Webrick? In your application, You would update it to the newest version 1.0.x. You can set as well, the edge version, pointing the github repo as source.

Comment: I don't think Thin is the problem here - Thin is very flexible with respect to the version of EventMachine. The problem is that the application I am cloning directly requires a version of EventMachine that is incompatible with Windows. Am I missing something here?

Comment: it was not the problem but it could help you to fix. Anyway, you decided to do exactly as i suggested. Version bigger than 1.0.x which fixes it.