# Rails, Windows and HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, https, eventmachine

**My objective is** to pass from a standard HTTP server to a more safe HTTPS one.

**My setup is:** Ruby 2.0.0p598, Rails 4.2.0, Thin 1.6.3, Windows 7-Pro-x64-SP1

**What I did:** Using a self-signed certificate I try to start the server with:

```
thin start --ssl --ssl-key-file ssl/server.key --ssl-cert-file ssl/server.crt
```

**What is the issue:** I receive the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Encryption not available on this event-machine

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

**My question to you:** Do you know if it is a general issue on Windows (therefore I cannot even think to succeed in doing it) or is there a way to let thin work with ssl on Windows?

Comment: In a _normal_ deployment you will have a web server in front of thin, which terminates SSL, and thin doesn't have to worry about it. Deploying on Windows is _not normal_ and is generally considered a bad practice (though some people do it anyway). Even so you can still place a normal web server in front of thin on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

This is a duplicate of: [Install OpenSSL with Ruby for eventmachine on Windows 7 x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968738/install-openssl-with-ruby-for-eventmachine-on-windows-7-x86/30758843#30758843)

I will put same answer as there:

using rubyinstaller-2.1.6.exe, DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx.exe and OpenSSL (http://slproweb.com/download/Win32OpenSSL-1_0_2c.exe or newer) in C:\OpenSSL

```
gem install eventmachine -- --with-ssl-dir=C:\OpenSSL
```

succeeds but then running thin with ssl fails in usual manner:

```
Encryption not available on this event-machine
```

You see above how to pass parameter to the native gem setup which should help you. We still need to find a set of parameters which will allow to built the thing correctly.

how to make

```
checking for main() in -lssl... no
```

a yes...?

after half a day of digging I have patched eventmachine to correctly search for ssl libs on windows so use below line in gemfile until changes are merged:

```
gem 'eventmachine', :github => 'krzcho/eventmachine', :branch => 'master'
```

before installing the bundle specify location of ssl (it must be full version of ssl with developer headers/libs)

```
bundle config build.eventmachine --with-ssl-dir=c:/OpenSSL
```

i also needed to make my own thin which is not activating another eventmachine so another line in gemfile is needed:

```
gem 'thin', :github => 'krzcho/thin', :branch => 'master'
```

unfortunately i still have problem when using non-self signed cert:
[thin rails server/eventmachine on windows does not work with custom certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059658/thin-rails-server-on-windows-does-not-work-with-custom-certificate) (case closed - wrong cert)